# Header to reappear when user scrolls up by value (100px)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I am using the following script to hide my header when the user scrolls down, and it only changes the CSS when the page is 200px from the top and scrolled down.

I am simply trying to have the class navbar applied when the user scrolls up & 100 from the bottom as well as when scrolled down and 200 from the top. 200 from the top is applied. I have prevented the header being hidden when at the top of the page, I also want to prevent it being shown when at the bottom until scrolled up 100px

HTML Header :

```
 <header> 
   <nav> 
   </nav> 
 </header
```

Script:

```
<script>
(function($) {
  var ost = 0;
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    var cOst = $(this).scrollTop();

 if(cOst > 200 && cOst > ost) {
   $('nav').addClass('fixed').removeClass('navbar');
}
else {
   $('nav').addClass('navbar').removeClass('fixed');
}

ost = cOst;
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

CSS:

```
 .navbar {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;  }

.fixed {
 top: -62px;}

nav {
margin:0;
padding:0px;
text-align:center;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-bottom: 2px solid #d5dbdb;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
top:0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0.9;
transition: all 200ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
-webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;    }
```

Any feedback, comments or help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks (Y)

Comment: can you show your html markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is keep another variable for `total` so you can count how far up the user scrolled and reset it to 0 when they scroll back down. Because of how the script was written though if the header was shown by scrolling up *any* scrolling down at all would hide it again, so I made a second total variable and named them `upTotal` & `downTotal`. You can change the amount scrolled up/down needed to show/hide the header by changing the values `(upTotal >= 100)` & `(downTotal >= 200)` respectively. Please let me know if this is not what you had in mind.

```
(function ($) {
    var ost = 0,
        upTotal = 0,
        downTotal = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var cOst = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (cOst > ost) {
            upTotal = 0;
            downTotal += (cOst - ost);
            if (downTotal >= 200) {
                $('nav').addClass('navbar').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        } else {
            downTotal = 0;
            upTotal += (ost - cOst);
            if (upTotal >= 100) {
                $('nav').addClass('fixed').removeClass('navbar');
            }
        }
        ost = cOst;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a very crude, but working [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gb4zm/1/).